# How to efectively organize your web project? (specially mutilanguage websites)

Tags: language-agnostic

I have my project folder, for instance, **myWeb**. In it there are various folders like **styles** (for CSS),
**scripts** (JS), **php** (for php scripts), and folders for 3 different languages, for instance: **en**(english), **sp** (spanish),
**cn** (chinese). This sometimes gives me problems because the index or default page should be in
the root directory but all my index pages are inside their language folder.

Is there a better way of organizing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about JS and PHP scripts which also could be language depended?

I would try to use [HTTP header accepted language](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html#z12) and use web server to choose and serve correct version of page.

This of course doesn't solve all problems with site using many languages -- i.e. duplicate scripts for each language version (this could be solved with `gettext` like functions).

Answer (score 0):

For my own part I dont have to organise it like that since I'm using gettext to translate to the requested locale. Although I use python & django the same thing can be applied in [php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php).